# django deserialize tries to encode input as ascii?

Tags: python, xml, django, unicode, python-unicode

The code:

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> objects = serializers.deserialize('xml', fixturestr)
>>> o = next(objects)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/xml_serializer.py", line 156, in next
    for event, node in self.event_stream:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/pulldom.py", line 232, in next
    rc = self.getEvent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/pulldom.py", line 265, in getEvent
    self.parser.feed(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc5' in position 565: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`fixturestr` is a unicode object. Eliminating non-ascii characters is not an option. How can I stop the deserializer from doing this?

Comment: Do you have `# encoding=utf8` at the top of your file?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac (1) this is at the console (2) console encoding is utf-8 (3) that has no relevance to the issue, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert your unicode object to string using [smart_str](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.smart_str):

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from django.core import serializers

objects = serializers.deserialize('xml', smart_str(fixturestr))
o = next(objects)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I discovered, although I see no need to guess the encoding. I know exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if passed a unicode object, the deserializer will somewhere try to encode it as unicode. To avoid this, it must be passed a bytestring:

```
objects = serializers.deserialize('xml', fixturestr.encode('utf8'))
```